# How to run multiple karma targets in Grunt?

Tags: gruntjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

We're using Grunt to build multiple, but similar, applications in one build.
It's a rather complex and large project with a folder for each application and a folder named share with lots of shared components.

**multiple karma targets**
Angular injects dependency by name (String) and our applications have files with the same names like HomeController, MenuController. This forces us to split up the karma targets per application so dependencies are loaded only from the shared and specific application being tested.

**Fatal error**
When using grunt to run the karma targets it only runs the first successful and fails to run the second. `Fatal error: listen EADDRINUSE` The error is somehow related to a port being used.

**Karma config (simplified)**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  'use strict';  

    config.set({
    autoWatch: false,
    basePath: '../',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'], 
    exclude: [],
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],   
    plugins: [
      'karma-html-reporter',
      'karma-junit-reporter',
      'karma-coverage',
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-brackets'
    ],
    singleRun: false,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG
  });
};
```

**Grunt-karma config**

```
var dep = [
  'bower_components/**/*.js',
  'app/shared/**/*.js',
];

module.exports = {
  options: {
    configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
    reporters: ['brackets', 'html', 'junit', 'coverage'],
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    port: 9002,
    singleRun: true
  },
  A: {
    options: {
      files: dep.concat([       
        'app/A/src/**/*.js'
      ]),      
    }
  },
  B: {
    options: {
      files: dep.concat([
        'app/B/src/**/*.js'
      ]),      
    }
  }
};
```

**How can I run both karma targets (A and B) in the same the grunt task?**
My guess is I have to either reset the karma server (phantomJs?) or run them as separate "sets" on the same target, but I can't find out how to do it.

Hope anyone out there might help! Thanks!

**Update1**
This [issue on github](https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma/pull/57) seems to address the same problem, but has not yet made it to a release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**workaround that works**
Remove the the `karma` tasks from the the distribution task.
Instead of trying to run multiple karma targets in one grunt task, you can execute multiple grunt commands separately from the command line (mainly on the continuous integration server. For development there is rarely a need to run all targets)

The command could be: (optional xxxxxx is any task you want to run after testing has completed)

```
grunt testA && grunt testB && grunt xxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just move your `port` option into the targets and choose a different port for each one?

```
 A: {
    options: {
      port: 9011,
      files: dep.concat([       
        'app/A/src/**/*.js'
      ]),      
    }
  },
  B: {
    options: {
      port: 9012,
      files: dep.concat([
        'app/B/src/**/*.js'
      ]),      
    }
  }
```